# How can I make a stateless widget into a stateful one?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I have to make a stateless widget into a stateful one, based on a changing string parameter. I tried to get the string from the actual widget, but I ran into an error

It is a colored indicator which changes its color after the status string, but I cannot get that string in the state class

I tried this, what should I do?

```
class ChStatus extends StatefulWidget{
  final String status1;
  //final String color;

  getStatus(){ return this.status1 }

  ChStatus(this.status1);

  @override

  _ChStatusState createState() => _ChStatusState();

}

class _ChStatusState extends State<ChStatus>{
  String status = widget.status1;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    switch (status) {
      case ("active"):
        return Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:10.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:7.0, top:7,right:7.0,bottom:7.0),
                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                )
            ),

            Text(
              //S.of(context).challengeTitle,
                status,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
            )
          ],
        );

      case ("pending"):
        return Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:10.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:7.0, top:7,right:7.0,bottom:7.0),
                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                )
            ),

            Text(
              //S.of(context).challengeTitle,
                status,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
            )
          ],
        );

      case ("rejected"):
        return Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:10.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:7.0, top:7,right:7.0,bottom:7.0),
                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                )
            ),

            Text(
              //S.of(context).challengeTitle,
                status,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
            )
          ],
        );

      case ("done"):
        return Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  size: 20.0,
                )
            ),

            Text(
              //S.of(context).challengeTitle,
                status,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
            )
          ],
        );

      default:
        return Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:10.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.device_unknown,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  size: 20.0,
                )
            ),

            Text(
              //S.of(context).challengeTitle,
                "Unknown",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
            )
          ],
        );
    }
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: Nor can you and nor do you need to (unless your architecture is bad). If you are worried about performance, then there are no performance differences between the two subclasses.

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Android Studio` or `VS Code`, you can easily use `Show Context Actions` by using `Alt + Enter` on Android Studio and right click on VS Code. Then simply click *Convert to StatefulWidget*.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

1st, we dont need to use this method. also you are missing `;` end of the line.

```
getStatus() {
    return this.status1;
  }
```

we can spimply use `widget.status1` to get the string.
even if you want to use that method.

use `initState()` to setData, like

```
class _ChStatusState extends State<ChStatus> {
  late String status;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    status = widget.getStatus();
  }
```

doesnt it solve your problem?